# Change Side Nav Bar on window size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I am trying to make a side nav for a website. So far I am using a `<nav>` element and filling it with `<li>` to create my side bar.

So far my code is below ***(p.s in-line styling is just for testing, I will be using an external css file later on)***:

```
<body>

<nav style="background: #3f9edd; height: 1000px; min-width: 200px; position:fixed;">
    <li style="position: relative; display: block; background: #2ecc71; width: 100%; height: 10%; padding: 33px 25px;">Home Area</li>
    <li style="position: relative; display: block; background: #2b87c3; width: 100%; height: 5%; padding: 33px 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">item one</li>
    <li style="position: relative; display: block; background: #2b87c3; width: 100%; height: 5%; padding: 33px 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">item two</li>
    <li style="position: relative; display: block; background: #2b87c3; width: 100%; height: 5%; padding: 33px 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">item three</li>
    <li style="position: relative; display: block; background: #2b87c3; width: 100%; height: 5%; padding: 33px 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">item four</li>
    <li style="position: relative; display: block; background: #2b87c3; width: 100%; height: 5%; padding: 33px 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">item five</li>
</nav>

<div class="container" ng-controller="projectController">
</div>
</body>
```

The above code outputs the following:

[image]

**Whats my issue!**

I am trying to change the side nav bar if the user resizes their window or maybe they access the site from a iPad or iPhone etc.

**If the screen is full-size display this (I am already displaying this)**

[image]

**But if the screen size goes below a certain size the nav bar automatically changes to:**

[image]

**I am not sure how to develop this functionality. Can anyone guide me in the right direction. If you need any more information please let me know.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Offtopic: you should wrap you `<li>`s inside an `<ul>` or `<ol>`. Ontopic: place the images and text in separate elements, for example: `<li><img/><span>text</span></li>`. Then use media queries to define if you want to see them or not. Big screen, show both, small screen, only show img, hide span.

Comment: You will need to use @media querys

Comment: @LinkinTED Thank you for the reply. By hiding the span to hide the text would that change the width of the nav bar automatically as displayed in the image above?

Comment: @user2190986, depends on your code. Read some tutorials (like https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) about media queries. By defining a break point, you can switch between different styles for different sizes.

Comment: The span trick would change the nav width only if you do not set any width propery on nav itsel. so the nav element would stretch as long as ts children.

Comment: do a search for css media queries, it allows you to change the layout based on screen size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres a pretty crude example with pure `css` but could be used as a base, you could add transitions ect to the breakpoint as well to make it look snazzier

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/XmeXEo?editors=110

**HTML**

```
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chrome"></i><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chrome"></i><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chrome"></i><span>Clients</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chrome"></i><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
nav{
  background:#2F404F;
  height: 100vh;
  width:auto;
  position:fixed;
  ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  li{
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    padding:20px 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    a{
      color:#FFF;
      text-decoration:none;
      font-size:1.3em;
      i{
        padding:0 5px 0 0;
      }
    }
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  span{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use jsfiddles instead of codepen, since it the link changes when you save a codepen. Nice answer

Comment: @Persijn Are you sure they change every time you save? seems to stay the same for me:x I just hate how jsfiddle doesn't live update haha

Comment: @NooBskie This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Have two different spans in your `li`.

```
<li style="position: relative; display: block; background: #2b87c3; width: 100%; height: 5%; padding: 33px 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid;"><span class="showLarge">Large vieport</span><span class="showTablet">Tablet vieport</span></li>
```

By default:

```
.showTablet {
    display: none;
}
```

For tablet viewports:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .showLarge {
        display: none;
    }
    .showTablet {
       display: block;
    }
}
```